# Capturing arguments passed to a constructor using class based decorator without breaking inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, python-decorators

Running the code below raises the following exception:

```
ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 22, in <module>
TypeError: MyDecorator.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
>
```

When an object derived from class Subclass is instanciated, I want to access all the arguments given to the constructor, from my decorator's code. I had to stop before because my current code breaks the inheritance. Could someone steer me in the right direction?

```
class MyDecorator:
    def __init__(self, original_class):
        self.original_class = original_class

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.original_class(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"Decorator: Creating instance with arguments: {args}, {kwargs}")
        return instance

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # Pass through attribute access to the original class
        return getattr(self.original_class, name)

@MyDecorator
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def additional_method(self):
        print("Additional method in SubClass")

# Creating an instance of the decorated base class
base_instance = BaseClass("foo", arg2="bar")
print(f"arg1: {base_instance.arg1}, arg2: {base_instance.arg2}")

# Creating an instance of the decorated subclass
sub_instance = SubClass("baz", arg2="qux")
print(f"arg1: {sub_instance.arg1}, arg2: {sub_instance.arg2}")

# Accessing additional method in the subclass
sub_instance.additional_method()
```

Comment: I did't actually understand what you're trying to do. Are you looking to implement proxy design pattern?

Comment: You already store the passed parameter in `init`. What parameters are you talking about?

Comment: Every time someone creates an instance of SubClass, I want to retrieve the arguments passed to the constructor within the __call__ method of my decorator. It should technically work but decorating the parent class like I did causes the error above when a child object is created.

Comment: `BaseClass` isn't a class; it's an instance of `MyDecorator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in the comment, I realize that a custom metaclass would be a simple solution. When you instantiate a class, you're actually calling the class' class' `__call__` method which is the metaclass' `__call__`.

You can do the interception there:

```py
class MyMeta(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Creating instance with arguments: {args}, {kwargs}")
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)


class BaseClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2


class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def additional_method(self):
        print("Additional method in SubClass")


# Creating an instance of the decorated base class
base_instance = BaseClass("foo", arg2="bar")
print(f"arg1: {base_instance.arg1}, arg2: {base_instance.arg2}")

# Creating an instance of the decorated subclass
sub_instance = SubClass("baz", arg2="qux")
print(f"arg1: {sub_instance.arg1}, arg2: {sub_instance.arg2}")

# Accessing additional method in the subclass
sub_instance.additional_method()
```

output:

```
Creating instance with arguments: ('foo',), {'arg2': 'bar'}
arg1: foo, arg2: bar
Creating instance with arguments: ('baz',), {'arg2': 'qux'}
arg1: baz, arg2: qux
Additional method in SubClass
```

The point is that the metaclass applies to the whole inheritance chain.

It is now much better because the `isinstance()` works normally. In your solution the type of the `BaseClass` would become `MyDecorator` which is wrong.